# Access to %1 is denied by Administrator policy %2

Tags: windows

1. Downloaded a file as a Administrator
2. Attempting to run the file as a Administrator
3. Fail

The below shows me trying runas Administrator *in addition* to being administrator - just to be sure; plus the actual message is included:

```
C:\install>runas /user:"Administrator" HaskellPlatform-2013.2.0.0-setup.exe
Enter the password for Administrator:
Attempting to start HaskellPlatform-2013.2.0.0-setup.exe as user "MY-PC\Administrator" ...
RUNAS ERROR: Unable to run - HaskellPlatform-2013.2.0.0-setup.exe
786: Access to HaskellPlatform-2013.2.0.0-setup.exe has been restricted by your Administrator by policy rule (null).
```

A. Hello? I am the Administrator and I definitely need to run this file. Why the heck the system has a mind of its own?

B. Where to look for the policy rule forbidding access? Windows 7. I tried the more obvious places in the properties of the file and containing folder, and added Full Control, but maybe I do not understand what else interferes with it.

Comment: What types of "controls" do you have in place? Virus protection, firewalls, etc? Might be relevant.

Comment: If you are logged in as a domain user, then a local Administrator account, will be unable to provided the require elevation for the process.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, the answer is:

1. start button, type "cmd", Ctrl+Shift+Enter
2. Confirm you want to permit any changes to the computer
3. Now started the installer - no question asked

I suppose, the difference is in where the "permit changes" dialog appears - during some operation the installer attempts (and which cannot handle this situation - e.g. if a specific error code is returned), or before the installer even starts.

Comment: All you are doing is running a elevated command prompt instead of a non elevated command prompt.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yes, I realize that. This is why I say "Surprisingly....". Yet, that made a difference.